# how can I extend options as global in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jquery plugin. It is a validation plugin. After form submission I want to send the data with ajax. I create a validate constructor and inherit it by prototype. But I can not use the defaults value outside the jquery namespace.

I want to use ops variable as a global variable as I can access it from javascript prototype. So, I need a effective way to do this.

```
    (function($){
      $.fn.validation = function(options){
        var ops = $.extend({}, $.fn.validation.defaults, options);   
        //wanna make ops as  global as I can access  from prototype
      };
    }(jQuery));

    $.fn.validation.defaults = {
        url: 'validation.php',
        methodType: 'post',
    };

    function Validate(){               // constructor
      this.error = [];
    }

    Validate.prototype = {

        constructor : Validate,

        submitForm : function(currentForm){
            var formData = new FormData(currentForm);
                $.ajax({
                    url: opt.url,                 //  wanna call like that.
                    type: opt.methodType,        
                    //   Don't wanna use  $.fn.validation.defaults.methodType
                    success: function(data){

                    },
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a variable `ops` under jquery object `$.ops` and return that object from a extended `jquery` function `$.fn.validation.options`

```
(function($){
   $.ops = {};

   $.fn.validation = function(options){
       $.ops = $.extend({}, $.fn.validation.defaults, options);   
      //wanna make ops as  global as I can access  from prototype
   };
   // expose the ops object to outside world
   $.fn.validation.options = function () {
       return this.ops;
   }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I have updated the source code to return only the required property instead of returning the object itself as it is dangerous, eg .if you update the ops property by mistake from outside the plugin,then options property will get corrupted.

Comment: I used global as: ops = $.extend({}, $.fn.validation.defaults, options); here ops is a object and you declared as $.obj. what is the basic difference among them?

Comment: Since ops is in global scope, ops is vulnerable to change outside the plugin as well. This is a bad practice. If you just define ops inside the plugin and return it's value,then ops value can be updated only when plugin initialised and not there after. This will keep your plugin stable

Comment: Instead of polluting the global scope of your script, i created a property under $ object ,which is a jquery object. It's best to define to property under its respective scope than declare in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare `ops` outside the `document.ready` function, leaving it in the `global scope` and then initiate it in your `document.ready` function, which is some `local scope`, so now you can use `ops` in any `local scope`.

**Note:** Be careful, `ops` will always be declared, but not always initiated. If your `document.ready` function wasn't called yet `ops` will be `undefined`.

```
// Global scope
var ops;

(function($){
  $.fn.validation = function(options){
    /// Local scope
    ops = $.extend({}, $.fn.validation.defaults, options);   
  };
}
```